# Javascript string count with rtrim

Tags: javascript, regex

so i have the string like this one(for example):

```
var str = '1234567  ' +
            '89';
```

two empty chars after *7* (can be more)
i have a regular expression

```
var text = str.replace(/(\r\n)|\r|\n|(&nbsp;)|(&#160;)|(\u00A0)/g, ' ')
                .replace(/<p>( |(<br>))<\/p>/gi, "\n")//weird TinyMCE newline variants
                .replace(/(\s*<\/p>)|(\s*<br[^<>]*>)|(\s*\n)/gi, "\n")
                .replace(/<.[^<>]*>/g, '')//strip tags
                .replace(/&[a-z]+;/g, 'a')//html_entity_decode
                .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');//whitespace right trim




console.log(text.length) //
```

result is *11* but it should be *9*.

How can i trim right whitespaces and empty things from string before newline(each new line).
text can be:

```
    var text = 'new     ' +
               'text         ' +
               'example ';
text.length should be 14
```

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nBk7j/117/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Replace) to remove every space. For individual strings, you could use [`String.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Use an array to hold the strings and then you could do this

```
var arr = ['new     ', 'text         ', 'example ']; // array of strings
var text = arr.map(function(str){ // map to create a new array
    return str.replace(/(\w+)\s+/, "$1");  // right trim
}).join(""); // join the array with empty string
console.log(text.length); // 14
```

Comment: thanks ok it works, but i need only right trim, left side empty chars should stay.